# Deploy custom ESB transport

Tags: wso2-esb

I've implemented a custom transport by extending the org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportListener class. I copied my jar file to the `WSO2_ESB_HOME\repository\components\dropins` folder. Upon startup I keep getting a NoClassDefFoundError (stack trace below). Can you please help me to correctly deploy my transport?

```
[2014-01-31 11:49:27,456] FATAL - CarbonServerManager WSO2 Carbon initialization Failed
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occured while loading the Axis configuration from E:\software\copyable\WSO2ES~1.0\bin\../repository/conf/axis2/a
xis2.xml
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:190)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:41)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1560)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:139)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org/apache/axis2/transport/TransportListener
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportReceivers(AxisConfigBuilder.java:632)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:308)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:188)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis2/transport/TransportListener
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.ChildFirstURLClassLoader.loadClass(ChildFirstURLClassLoader.java:62)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.processTransportReceivers(AxisConfigBuilder.java:625)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.populateAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:308)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.createNewConfigurationContext(CarbonConfigurationContextFactory.java:65)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:398)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

A normal jar go to `repository/components/lib`

`repository/components/dropins` is reserved for osgi bundles

Answer (score 0):

Following is the definition of dropins and lib directories.

**dropins (/repository/components/dropins):** You can deploy third party OSGi bundles into dropins directory.

**lib (/repository/components/lib):** You can deploy third party jar files (non OSGi) to lib directory. At the time when the server starts, the server will convert any jar files located in lib folder into OSGi bundles. These converted OSGi bundles are placed into the dropins directory.

**So you should put the compiled jar into lib directory.**